# How to solve RuntimeError - models conflicting in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models, runtime-error

I am trying to connect an external mysql db to Django only for reading data. I have followed the instruction according to the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/) to connect multi-DB. However, when I try to `makemigration`/ `migrate` the new DB, it returns the error as follows shown. I have do some research on google and found that not many solution out there and can solve my problem. Its my first time to see this and have no idea whats the reason leading the error. I import the models by `inspectdb` and TotalopennumTmp is one of the models in DB. Thanks for helping me solve this problem.

```
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/app/app/models.py", line 1007, in <module>
    class TotalopennumTmp(models.Model):
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 309, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 221, in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'totalopennumtmp' models in application 'app': <class 'app.app.models.TotalOpennumTmp'> and <class 'app.app.models.TotalopennumTmp'>.
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
          'default': {
              'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
              'NAME': 'local',
              #skip the detail
          },
          'afe':{
              'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
              'NAME': 'myapp_db',
              'USER': 'root',
              'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
              'HOST': 'mysql_host',
              'PORT': 'mysql_port',
          }
  }

  DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MyAppRouter',]
```

routers.py

```
class MyAppRouter:
      def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
          if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
              return 'myapp_db'
          return None

      def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
          if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or \
             obj2._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
              return True
          return None

      def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None,  **hints):
          if app_label == 'myapp':
              return db == 'myapp_db'
          return None

      def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
          #make sure myapp only appear on myapp_db db
          if db == 'myapp_db':
              return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp'
          elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
              return False
          return None
```

models.py

```
class TotalOpennumTmp(models.Model):
    #some field
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'total_opennum_tmp'

class TotalopennumTmp(models.Model):
    #some field
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'totalopennum_tmp'
```

Comment: seems you have two classes `TotalOpennumTmp` and `TotalopennumTmp` in your models.py that have almost the same name except the "O" vs "o". That's probably not what you want. But if it is, you can specify the corresponding table name using `db_table` in the `Meta` options.

Comment: @Alasdair I have updated the two models crashed

Comment: @dirkgroten Oh, I see. Thanks. Since its an external db and I imported the models by 'inspectdb' , which had already defined 'db_table'  and I do want to keep the two corresponding tables. I am not sure whether I should change the 'db_table'.

Comment: It looks as if Django doesn’t let you have two models with the same lowercase names - try renaming one of them, e.g. `TotalopennumTmp2`. You already have `db_table`, so Django will use the correct table.

Comment: Rename your models then. It doesn't make sense to have two models with the same name anyway.